# How to delete N documents based on any given field of that document?

Tags: mongodb

I intend to delete a large number of documents from a collection. My collection has more than a million documents. My idea is say, query for 10k documents based on a common field and delete all of them. I'm not sure how to get this done. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a deleteMany, see the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/remove-documents/#id1)